# Core Data, Notification in main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have in my code like this :

```
- (id)init
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(userDataDidUpdate)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                   object:[UserData managedObjectContext]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)userDataDidUpdate
{
   // notification received...
}
```

and in an other class ( CoreData manager) i am doing like this :

```
[[UserData managedObjectContext] performBlock:^{

                     NSError *error;
                     if (![[UserData managedObjectContext] save:&error])
                     {
                         // handle error
                     }

                     isSyncing = NO;
                     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NDUserDataSyncDidUpdateLocalData object:nil];

                     }];
```

The problem is that i send the notification in the performBlock of the managed objectContext and it's not the main thread. How can i send the notification inside the performBlcok in the main thread ?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't using `NSNotificationCenter` the way to do cross thread notification. If you post in one thread, all other thread will receive the notification.

Comment: @rckoenes But Apple says that  we should post and receive the notification in the same thread, no ? can i post a notification in a background thread and receives it in the main thread ? if yes is this a good practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are those two snippets related? There are different notifications registered to/sent.

Anyway, you can do the following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NDUserDataSyncDidUpdateLocalData object:nil];        
});
```

P.S. I hope you remove observer from notification center in dealloc method.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple with GCD, just wrap it like this:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NDUserDataSyncDidUpdateLocalData object:nil];
});
```

Note that i used `dispatch_sync` here and not `dispatch_async`, since you usually want your notifications to be completely processed, before returning from the call to `postNotificationName:...`.